# ByteBuddy intercept the calls toward specific class instances inside the bytecode of a method

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have a class A with a method m() and a class B with a method n().
In A I have a field b of type B.
In m() there is at some point a call to b.n().
I need to change the code of A with ByteBuddy in order to do some action before and after the b.n() call.
I need some advice/tips/hint to attack the problem.

Thanks in advance,

Radu

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this in Byte Buddy by writing custom byte code using the underlying ASM API. Byte Buddy does not offer any high-level constructs to alter any code within a method.

The API is exposed by registering an AsmVisitorWrapper.

Alternatively, you could create a subclass of B.n() where you add this interception logic and set it as the field of A. This would however affect all invokations via A.

Comment: Thanks! I will dig with AsmVisitorWrapper. The ASM API is impressive and I need to be in a good shape to be able to attack it, but that is life. :) I didn't find yet a way to access the statements in sequence, store them in a place, and put them back to the method (after modified them). Perhaps there is slightly different approach to deal with. Thanks again for your kind answer, Radu